# Getting error No qualifying bean of type 'com.cav.controllers.repository.UserRepository' SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am getting the following error running my application.
No qualifying bean of type 'com.cav.controllers.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

I have a repository interface

```
package com.cav.controllers.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.cav.models.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>{

}
```

And a simple controller

```
@Controller
public class AddController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/addUser")
    public ModelAndView addUser(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        System.out.println("Running method addUser");
        String param1 = req.getParameter("t1");
        String param2 = req.getParameter("t2");
        String param3 = req.getParameter("t3");
        
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        User user = new User(param1,param2,param3);
        userRepository.save(user);
        //userService.saveUser(user);
        mv.setViewName("displayUser.jsp");
        mv.addObject("userID", param1);
        mv.addObject("fname", param2);
        mv.addObject("sname", param3);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

My main app

```
package com.cav;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebBankMvcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebBankMvcApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My controllers-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    
    
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.cav.controllers"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

I cant see what is wrong my repository is in the path

```
package com.cav.controllers.repository
```

So it should be able to see the jparepository and autowire it.

Comment: `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.cav.controllers.repository"})` and probably remove your XML file

Comment: The XML isn't loaded and thus useless. You don't need `@EnableJpaRepositories` with Spring Boot if you adhere to the recommended package structure. Please add the full stacktrace to your question instead of the snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. The controllers-servlet.xml is loaded. This is SpringMVC, and its so I have a form addUser, which is mapped to addUser, and it calls the controller AddController and the method addUser. The servlet.xml does the mapping.
I have to do more research on Spring MVC with repos. There is something I am missing